# Read structured binary data one record at a time into numpy buffer

Tags: python, memory-management, numpy, buffer, binaryfiles

I have to read millions of records from a structured binary file. While reading, I'd like to transform the data into a more useful memory layout. Each record is quite large. The total file size is about 30GB.

I could use `numpy.fromfile`, but the system I'm running on has sufficient memory for only *one* full array, as such I cannot load the entire file, then copy everything into the final array in memory, and then destroy the initially loaded array.

I could also use `numpy.fromfile` to read chunks, but I'm worried that `numpy.fromfile` will create and destroy a new array every time instead of reusing a buffer array. I haven't tested this yet, but I suspect this would result in some serious memory spikes and slow garbage collection.

In case this applies: the files are loader over infiniband and the analyses I'm running on it require that I loop over the entire dataset numerous times. I use Cython for these loops, so any C code that could help is welcome, but I would prefer to get it done in Python.

Comment: Sounds like you need to create a Proxy to a memory-mapped file.

Answer (score 0):

From what you describe, it sounds like you could use [`np.memmap`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.memmap.html) to create a memory map to the input binary file stored on disk. An `np.memmap` array behaves the same as a standard `np.ndarray` in most respects. You can index it as you would a normal array, and pass it to any function that would accept an `np.ndarray`. Behind the scenes your OS will handle the business of reading, caching and writing the appropriate parts of your binary file, preventing you from inadvertently reading a chunk that is too big to fit in RAM.

You might then, for example, create a second memmap to store the output, then iterate over the biggest slices of the input memmap you can handle in core memory, transform them however you like, and write them to the corresponding positions in the output memmap.

If you're looking for a better output format to store your data, I'd strongly suggest you also look into HDF5 (e.g. [h5py](http://www.h5py.org) or [PyTables](http://www.pytables.org)), which offers portability, on-the-fly compression and much faster average read/write times, amongst other benefits.